# Mac OS X Server Code Signing Certificate Renew Failure

Tags: macos, ssl, server, certificate

Got an alert on server that the certificate is going to expire. I click the "renew" button and it says Unknown Error. So I dig deeper and run the following on the command line

```
sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/certadmin --recreate-CA-signed-certificate "macserver.local Code Signing Certificate" "IntermediateCA_MACSERVER.LOCAL_1" dd3d0ec3
```

to which i got the following error:

```
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/certadmin --recreate-CA-signed-certificate: Unable to renew identity 'macserver.local Code Signing Certificate': unable to renew certificate: could not find original certificate 'macserver.local Code Signing Certificate' with serial number 'dd3d0ec3' issued by 'IntermediateCA_MACSERVER.LOCAL_1' (-25300)
```

So I run the following to search the certificate and it does find it:

```
sudo security find-certificate -c "macserver.local Code Signing Certificate"
keychain: "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
class: 0x80001000 
attributes:
"alis"<blob>="macserver.local Code Signing Certificate"
"cenc"<uint32>=0x00000003 
"ctyp"<uint32>=0x00000001 
"hpky"<blob>=0xA14502C168EB2D717615AA60535926B760804C8F  "\241E\002\301h\353-qv\025\252`SY&\267`\200L\217"
"issu"<blob>=0x308193312A302806035504030C21496E7465726D65646961746543415F46494C455345525645522E4C4F43414C5F3131123010060355040A0C09727472616374696F6E312D302B060355040B0C244D41434F5358204F70656E4469726563746F727920496E7465726D6564696174652043413122302006092A864886F70D010901161361646D696E40727472616374696F6E2E636F6D  "0\201\2231*0(\006\003U\004\003\014!IntermediateCA_MACSERVER.LOCAL_11\0220\020\006\003U\004\012\014\011macserver1-0+\006\003U\004\013\014$MACOSX OpenDirectory Intermediate CA1"0 \006\011*\206H\206\367\015\001\011\001\026\023mymacserver@gmail.com"
"labl"<blob>="macserver.local Code Signing Certificate"
"skid"<blob>=<NULL>
"snbr"<blob>=0x00DD3D0EC3  "\000\335=\016\303"
"subj"<blob>=0x30553132303006035504030C2966696C657365727665722E6C6F63616C20436F6465205369676E696E6720436572746966696361746531123010060355040A0C09727472616374696F6E310B3009060355040613025553  "0U1200\006\003U\004\003\014)macserver.local Code Signing Certificate1\0220\020\006\003U\004\012\014\011macserver1\0130\011\006\003U\004\006\023\002US"
```

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem for my cert. Instead of using hexadecimal, i use decimal. So in your case the serial number should be 3711766211 in decimal.

Hope this will help you too.

Thanks

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) there are to lift your quality content up

Comment: ahh I see.. Thanks for that. :)